# Can't change \title font size when using tex4ebook

Tags: tex4ebook

In my mwe I change the font size for `\title` and `\author` to `HUGH`. I can see the change in my generated PDF but when I convert the tex to epub using `tex4ebook -l main.tex` only the size of `\author` changes. The size of `\title` is much smaller and seems fixed--it stays the same regardless of what I enter for a font size?

How can I specify the font size for `\title` that will be recognized in my .epub after I convert the tex to epub using tex4ebook?

**EDIT:** Never mind. I saw the issue when I loaded the epub in Mac Books. When I load the epub in ReadEra, I see NONE of the font sizes for `\maketitle` are observed. I think I'm learning the ebook readers are a bit of the wild west and that we have to format for the least common denominator. I.e., keep the formatting very simple. Does that ring true?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\title{{\HUGE The Really Big Book}}
\author{{\HUGE Roger Smith}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
The doc contents.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to style your title. If you take a look at the HTML code generated by the `\maketitle` command, it looks like this:

```html
<div class='maketitle'>


<h2 class='titleHead'>The Really Big Book</h2>
 <div class='author'><span class='cmr-17x-x-143'>Roger Smith</span></div><br />
<div class='date'></div>
   </div>
```

So you need to style the  `titleHead` class that is child element of `<div>` with the `maketitle` class. You can style it using the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{.maketitle  .titleHead{font-size:3rem;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Css` command can be used to pass CSS information. You can change the `font-size` value to your liking. Compile it using:

```
$ tex4ebook -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]